# internal representation of varchar type in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am wondering how MySQL stores varchar type under the hood? Will it be stored off the table separately or will it be stored as fixed size field (something like 2 byte unicode array)?

Comment: I disagree. Understanding how your database is storing things internally is important when programming as it will shape your strategy.

Comment: @tadman Again, not suited for SO. There is a dba.se site that would be more appropriate.

Comment: Or in more detail in this part of the documentation . . . http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VARCHAR` is a variable length field that's stored in the row itself. It's stored in whatever character set you employ, usually UTF-8 if you're going with a sensible default.

Remember the length of the field is a maximum, not a fixed size. `VARCHAR(255)` can store up to 255 *characters*, which in MySQL translates to up to 255 3-byte UTF-8 sequences, or 765 bytes total.

`TEXT` and `BLOB` type fields are stored in a separate area of the table.

See more in the [data types documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-type-overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.

Please refer this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///char.html which will tell you the difference between char and varchar

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your posts since your avatar and name are already automatically attached to all of them.